# The operation could not be completed. No such interface supported (Ruby In Steel)

Tags: ruby, ironruby

I installed Ruby In Steel Trial Edition for Visual Studio 2008
and when I try to save an IronRuby Project, it keep warning:

> "The operation could not be completed. No such interface supported".

I cannot save the project but only run it.

Comment: Nearly 8 months on and this has solved the sae problem for me in a Blackberry plug in.  Thanks. +1 - surely what stack overflow is all about :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably: Either your installation is corrupt or, you have hit upon a VS bug. See this blog [post](http://vsx-insider.blogspot.com/2008/02/new-custom-project-can-be-saved.html) and the corresponding [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=285937) filed with MS.

Comment: Nearly 8 months on and this has solved the sae problem for me in a Blackberry plug in.  Thanks. +1 - surely what stack overflow is all about :)

Answer (score 13):

Just restarting Visual Studio solves the problem sometimes.

Comment: i upgraded from VS17 to VS19 and got this error when opening a VS17 project. Restarting VS resolved it (reloading project did not)